# Allow an account access to only one mobile app and browser on website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing a task that allow an account access to only one mobile app and browser on website(When login on other mobile app or browser on website, this current mobile app or browser website will return to login page when call APi). My idea is creating Dictionary> on AddSingleton Class to save userName and Token.
The request call to API will check whether this account and token are existed on Dictionary> or not. Everything work on local (dev) but when i deploy on server,
Dictionary> clear (dispose) all value saved before automatically . 
Anybody know why or have any idea for this issue. Thanks all.

Declare On Startup:

```
services.AddSingleton<DictionaryAccount, DictionaryAccount>();
```

Event When Call Api On Startup:

```
OnTokenValidated = AdditionalValidation
```

Fuction AdditionalValidation on startup:

```
public Task AdditionalValidation(TokenValidatedContext context)
        {
            bool check = true;

            var securityToken = context.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
            var claim = securityToken.Claims.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Type == "unique_name");
            //1 - web ; 2 - mobile
            var platform = securityToken.Claims.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Type == "platform");
            try
            {
                if (TurnOff != 1)
                {
                    if (platform.Value != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int type = int.Parse(platform.Value);
                            string email = securityToken.Claims.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Type == "Email").Value;
                            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(securityToken.RawData))
                            {
                                using (var serviceScope = _app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
                                {

                                    var _context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DictionaryAccount>();
                                    check = _context.CheckValidSession(type, email, securityToken.RawData, _logger);
                                }
                            }                                                    
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            _logger.LogError("Fail login startUp " + e.ToString());
                            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable;
                            context.Fail("Failed additional validation");
                        }
                    }
                    if (!check)
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable;
                        context.Fail("Failed additional validation");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                _logger.LogError("Fail login startUp " + e.ToString());
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable;
                context.Fail("Failed additional validation");
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Function CheckValidSession:

```
public bool CheckValidSession(int type, string email, string token, ILogger<AuthController> _logger)
        {
            string outConnection;
            try
            {
                //1 - web ; 2 - mobile
                _logger.LogWarning("login write log email: " +email);
                _logger.LogWarning("login write log type: " +type);
                _logger.LogWarning("login write log token: " + token);
                _logger.LogWarning("login write log list" + string.Join(",", accountListWebsite.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray()));

                var item = accountListWebsite.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("Token In list: " + string.Join(",", accountListWebsite.Select(x => x.Value).ToList()[0].ToArray()));
                }


                if (type == 1)
                {
                    if (accountListWebsite[email].TryGetValue(token, out outConnection))
                    {
                        _logger.LogWarning("return true");
                        return true;
                    }
                } 
                else if(type == 2)
                {
                    if (accountListMobile[email].TryGetValue(token, out outConnection))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Exception return false " + e.ToString(), e.Message);
                bool check = false;
                return check;
            }
        }
```

Function CreateDictionaryAccountWeb: -> called this function when login success

```
public bool CreateDictionaryAccountWeb(string email, string token, int count, ILogger<AuthController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            Count = count;
            bool result = true;
            try
            {
                lock (accountListWebsite)
                {
                    HashSet<string> emails;
                    if (!accountListWebsite.TryGetValue(email, out emails))
                    {
                        emails = new HashSet<string>();
                        accountListWebsite.Add(email, emails);
                    }
                    _logger.LogWarning("login write log " + string.Join(",", accountListWebsite.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray()));
                    lock (accountListWebsite)
                    {
                        if (emails != null && emails.Count >= 0) {
                            if (!emails.Any(x => x.Contains(token))) {
                                if (emails.Count >= count)
                                {
                                    var temp = emails.First();
                                    if (temp != token)
                                        emails.Remove(temp);
                                }

                                _logger.LogWarning("login token " + token);
                                emails.Add(token);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            emails.Add(token);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Fail login" + e.ToString());
                result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

[My Log:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpBMT.png)

Comment: Is your web server on Azure or other hosting service provider? Is your app hosted in IIS? If so, check if your app's application pool has been recycled on idle. Usually cloud service does that once app goes idle.

Comment: weichch - when UAT this website app hosted in IIS on windows server 2012 r2, and production on Azure.